# How to write a byte array to a part of exist file?

Tags: java, android, io

Pls help me this. I have a file(Not a text file). I read a part of the file then I convert it into a byte array and I do something with the array. So, Can I erase the part of the file and write my own byte array into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RandomAccessFile. Move the file-pointer to the required position and rewrite

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that, provided in case of some files it may become corrupted. Here in the sample I am copying only half of the bytes from the real file and writing it to a new file which gives a partial image written to file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("D:\\Penguins.jpg");
        byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(bFile);
        fileInputStream.close();

        byte[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(bFile, (int) file.length() / 2);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\partialPenguins.jpg");
        out.write(newArray);
        out.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read it into the memory, convert, do whatever you wish, assemble a whole file, and write in it's entiriety to the disk, replacing the old one.